# How can i get re-colored mesh percantage?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vertices

I'm trying to paint according to the triangles and vertexes of the object. I've done these, but I want to instantly show how much of the object the player/user has painted. Thus, when it reaches a certain rate, I will end the game. But I don't know how to get the percentage rate.

thank you in advance for your help

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrXKt.jpg

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class VertexPainterSec : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private MeshRenderer meshRenderer;
    [SerializeField] private Mesh mesh;
    [SerializeField] Vector3[] vertices;
    [SerializeField] Color[] colorArray;
    [SerializeField] public Text colorPercentage;

    private void Start()
    {
        mesh = transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
        vertices = mesh.vertices;

        colorArray = new Color[vertices.Length];
        for (int k = 0; k < vertices.Length; k++)
        {
            colorArray[k] = Color.white;
        }
        mesh.colors = colorArray;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit))
            {            

                int[] triangles = mesh.triangles;
                var vertIndex1 = triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 0];
                var vertIndex2 = triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 1];
                var vertIndex3 = triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 2];

                colorArray[vertIndex1] = Color.red;
                colorArray[vertIndex2] = Color.red;
                colorArray[vertIndex3] = Color.red;

                mesh.colors = colorArray;
                colorPercentage.text = "Color Percantage";
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("no hit");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you could do this:

The first is by running a function that calculates the total number of non-white colors in `colorArray` like so

```
void CalculatePercentage()
        {
            int totalPainted = 0;
            foreach (var c in colorArray)
            {
                if (c != Color.White)
                {
                    totalPainted++;
                }
            }
            colorPercentage = "Color Percantage: %" + (totalPainted / colorArray) * 100;            
        }
```

This has some drawbacks though as its very inefficient since you're counting every item in the array every time you run this, and it would only work if your base color is white

The second method involves keeping track of how many vertices you've painted as you're going, you'd have to modify your code slightly like so:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class VertexPainterSec : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private MeshRenderer meshRenderer;
    [SerializeField]
    private Mesh mesh;
    [SerializeField]
    Vector3[] vertices;
    [SerializeField]
    Color[] colorArray;
    [SerializeField]
    public Text colorPercentage;
    //This value will track how many vertices you've painted
    [SerializeField]
    private int paintedVertices;
    private void Start()
    {
        //Initialize the value
        paintedVertices = 0;
        mesh = transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
        vertices = mesh.vertices;
        colorArray = new Color[vertices.Length];
        for (int k = 0; k < vertices.Length; k++)
        {
            colorArray[k] = Color.white;
        }

        mesh.colors = colorArray;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit))
            {
                int[] triangles = mesh.triangles;
                var vertIndex1 = triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 0];
                var vertIndex2 = triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 1];
                var vertIndex3 = triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 2];
                //Only paint and add to paintedVertices if the color is white
                //to avoid constantly adding to the paintedVertices value
                if (colorArray[vertIndex1] == Color.white)
                {
                    colorArray[vertIndex1] = Color.red;
                    paintedVertices++;
                }

                if (colorArray[vertIndex2] == Color.white)
                {
                    colorArray[vertIndex2] = Color.red;
                    paintedVertices++;
                }

                if (colorArray[vertIndex3] == Color.white)
                {
                    colorArray[vertIndex3] = Color.red;
                    paintedVertices++;
                }

                mesh.colors = colorArray;
                //Calculate the percentage by dividing the
                //paintedVertices value by the total number of vertices
                colorPercentage.text = "Color Percantage: %" + (paintedVertices / colorArray.Length) * 100;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("no hit");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello first of all thank you for the reply. I tried both methods, but it still doesn't show how much it has been painted instantly. In addition, when they are all painted, it becomes 1%.

Comment: Whoops my bad, I forgot to multiply the values by 100 to get the percentage

Comment: The only problem is it doesn't show run time but that's enough for me, thanks a million,